# EOFError while trying to run rmate algorithm on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have been trying to setup Sublime Text 3 on my local Windows 10 machine to work remotely on files on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTE server (google cloud compute engine instance). I followed these instructions: https://github.com/henrikpersson/rsub and https://github.com/textmate/rmate

I have decided to use a standalone bash version (though I apparently still needed to install ruby environment).

I have setup my rmate script in /bin/ catalogue, but when I try to run the command rmate on my remote Ubuntu server through ssh, I get the following end of a line error:

```
/bin/rmate:145:in `readline': end of file reached (EOFError)
    from /bin/rmate:145:in `handle_cmd'
    from /bin/rmate:180:in `connect_and_handle_cmds'
    from /bin/rmate:223:in `block in <main>'
    from /bin/rmate:222:in `fork'
    from /bin/rmate:222:in `<main>'
```

I have tried simply reinstalling the script from the link provided, but it didn't help. I also made sure that the rest of my installation: config file on my local machine and my firewall rules and sshd config files are correct.

I would be grateful if you pointed me in the direction of what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same error when I connecting raspberry PI and doing remote coding from Visual Studio Code.

I try to reconnect SSH with IP address **127.0.0.1** instead of host name **localhost**.

After that try to open **rmate** again.

[image]

Comment: did that solve your problem?